# Restricting access to an action from outside of website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, security

I have an ASP.Net MVC3 web application written in C#.

I have one ActionResult that has been designed to return a Json result so that it can be called asynchronously by a webpage using JavaScript. The action is basically as follows:

```
public ActionResult FindSomething(string search)
{
   var result = GetSearchResult(search);

   return Json(new { @Result = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then in one of the web pages I have some JavaScript (using JQuery) to get the data.

What I want to try and do however is to restrict access to this FindSomething Action so that only my website code can get access to the result. As it stands anybody could call this Action from a web browser.

Any ideas on some options for me to get this done?

It should be noted that there will be no login to this website so no authentication can be done that way. And I do not want to have anything in the html source code relating to a password approach.

---

**Why I want this**:

The `FindSomething` method actually calls a third party service, which is paid for using credits. So in effect, the number of calls, the more it costs.

My concern is, if someone knows about this URL and wants to use the same service then they could query it by our URL and avoid the charge.

I am not sure if this 3rd party service has even consider this, they offer a couple of ways to interact with the service. One through a web service which I can call via server code (which I am doing) and one through some inline javascript references - the latter of which requires hard-coded license key in the html source :S

...it may be worth me hitting them up for an answer, but regardless of how I get around this flaw in the service, it still makes for an interesting question here on SO

Comment: As the answer below says, there's no way to do this given your constraints. Why do you want to do it though? If you're happy to let the whole world have access to this function through your website, what's the problem with letting people call it in other ways? (That's not a rhetorical question: the answer might suggest another way to achieve your goal)

Comment: You could look at the HTTP Referer but even that can be added as a header

Comment: @jimw: ...your wish is my command (aka see edit)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. In light of your edit, I'd say you really should be requiring a login for this action! Even worse, if this license key is what it sounds like, not only can a naughty person cost you money out of pure malice, he can also take your key and use the service you're paying for without going through your server at all. I don't suppose you want to name the service or paste an example, so I can't be sure they haven't done something clever to get around these problems, but on what you've posted here it sounds dangerous for you.

Comment: @jimw: The service is [PostcodeAnywhere](http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/) - I am using the address lookup based on the postcode of the user. As you can imagine, this kind of thing could be commonly used for non-registered users and therefore there will be no login

Comment: Ah yes, I see why you don't want to require a login for it. In that case, I'd pass all access to that service through your server and implement some rate-limiting on it. Perhaps keep a daily log of IPs and only allow a certain number of lookups per IP. Once the limit is reached you can detect it and gracefully degrade, so that if a legit user accidentally exceeds the limit he's not confronted with an error  message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that there's no reliable way to achieve that given your constraints. You could make it difficult by using for example anti forgery tokens but not 100% bullet-proof. Don't forget that not only browsers can send HTTP requests. Anyone can forge an HTTP request and send it to your server.

The way this is done with non GUI APIs is that public keys are given to clients and the way this is done with GUI applications such as web sites is by giving passwords to your users.

Comment: hmmm... not sure exactly what you mean, but you have given my an idea (which might be what you mean anyway)... Something like creating a token in session that is rendered to the page, and then passing that token back as authentication?

Comment: [Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) using ASP.NET MVC’s AntiForgeryToken() helper](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/)

Comment: @zimdanen, as I said, CSRF is not bullet-proof. This doesn't ensure that the request comes from your website. It prevents CSRF attacks.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - Right; that link was meant for musefan, actually, in response to his comment.  I should have been more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Most sane way of doing it would be to use an anti-forgery token + salt as explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267694/Security-in-ASP-NET-MVC-by-using-Anti-Forgery-Toke):

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Salt = Constants.AntiForgeryTokenSalt)]
public ActionResult FindSomething(string search) { ... }
```

You can now couple this with 'authentication token' like below which will secure the action against both cross site scripting and unauthorized access:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Salt = Constants.AntiForgeryTokenSalt)]
public ActionResult FindSomething(string search, string accessToken) { ... }
```

Of course, under normal circumstances, 'access token' is obtained through some form of authentication mechanism (i.e. OAuth). In this case, it can be your improvised unique string passed to view and requested back (just as anti forgery token but with 'nonce' so that it can only be used once).

Comment: That's not something that you can rely upon. A hacker could perfectly fine forge an initial request to the web page, get the antiforgery cookie and forge the subsequent request.

Comment: Yes for that purpose, it should be coupled with some form of 'nonce' verification as I propose. Of course, it will never be 100% bullet-proof if not coupled with credentials check, I accept that.